# In ChartJS how do I change the color of a label in the legend?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got the following function making doughnut charts in ChartJS, the function imports the data, label text, and the id of the element.  For some reason the options legend labels does not work for me.  The default color of '#666' is not usable for my site's layout either.

my function:

```
function newDoughnutChart(id, labels, data) {
    var donutChartCanvas = $(id).get(0).getContext('2d')
    var donutData = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            }
        ]
    }
    var donutOptions = {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        options: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                    fontColor: "#fff",
                }
            }
        }
    }
    new Chart(donutChartCanvas, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: donutData,
        options: donutOptions
    })
}
```

backgroundColor is a variable I've set globally for this js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legend config has been moved to the `plugins section`

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It turns out I am using 2.9.4, which meant it wasn't in plugins, and my problem was an improper options object!  Thanks though, Your answer helped me find the problem after all!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but are you able to have two colors inside of the label colors? Like if I have two values and I want their label to match the color of the lines in the graph. It doesn't like having an array in there. Cheers for all your comments throughout the years, theyve helped me a ton!

Comment: You can check my answer here for how to achieve that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72087662/8682983

Answer (score 2):

```
    var donutOptions = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
              display: true,
              labels: {
                  color: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Really copy pasting my answer with a slightly different value for your collor

Comment: Didn't copy anything. Please check the timing, we posted the answer almost at the same time. I have edited the code that was shared by the author. If you still have issues, please let me know I will delete this.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the color by grabbing the class of that div tag using CSS selector. But It's not the best idea because it will change the color in your whole app.

Comment: This is not true, chart.js renders on a canvas so there is no div to style the text of

Comment: Okay, but there should be the CSS class right?

Comment: you can see the css class of canvas by inspecting the page.

Comment: Sorry. It's possible in ReactJS so I thought it will work here too.